# Implementation IScrollSnapPointsInfo

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, user-controls, winrt-xaml

I'm creating a UserControl that must implement the IScrollSnapPointsInfo interface. But so far I have not found any good examples of using this interface. Can anyone help me?